# MacOS - One line command is working in terminal but not in .sh script?

Tags: macos, shell, sh

MacOS High Sierra

I have a command that I currently use in terminal:

```
find /private/my/tmp -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -not -name -specialfolder -exec rm -r {} \;
```

which searches the folder private/my/tmp and removes all folders except one that is named "specialfolder".

This is working perfectly from the terminal, but I cannot get it working as .sh shell script. I have used `chmod +x /scripts/myscript.sh` to make it executable but this has not made any difference.

The shell script is:

```
#!/bin/sh
find /private/my/tmp -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -not -name -specialfolder -exec rm -r {} \;
```

Running it from the terminal as "sh myscript.sh" does not produce any result, no errors, nothing.

What do I need to fix to get this to work as a .sh script?

*PS - I had considered it may be a permissions issue, but I have set permissions with chmod -R 777 on the /private/my/tmp folder and still no difference.*

Comment: It looks like it should work, and if there were a permissions problem you should've gotten an error message to that effect. Try running it with `sh -x myscript.sh`, and it'll print the command before it executes it so you can see if it's doing anything weird. BTW, normally, the proper way to execute the script is with `./myscript.sh` (no `sh` command); that way, the shebang line has control of how it runs.

Comment: Worked at it some more, run the command you suggested, didn't show anything useful. Turns out it that it was a permissions problem even though it didn't say so. Permissions on the top-level folder, bottom-level folder and file were fine, seems that the permissions on the "my" subfolder were different and so preventing it from running correctly.

Answer (score 0):

This might not help anyone, but I was having similar issues with commands working but scripts not working. My problem is that I was developing the scripts on a Windows PC and deploying them to the Mac with incorrect EOL (end of line) characters. The script wouldn't run because the file was misformatted, but if I copied and pasted the commands into a terminal session via Addigy or a remote desktop session, then it worked.

running `sh -v myscript.sh` (the -v is for verbose) showed me the ^M (Windows EOL format) characters in my script and tipped me off to the error. Because the first line of the script is a comment, and the incorrect EOL character meant that the whole file got concatenated to one line, the rest of the script didn't run at all, so sh/bash never got the chance to even tell me that it couldn't parse the script.

notepad++ let me convert the EOL characters in by going to Edit > EOL Conversion > Unix (LF). There's an option for Mac (CR), but that's for much older Macs.

Hope that helps a future searcher. Enjoy!